# How to break a geometry into blocks?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, partitioning

I am certain there is already some algorithm that does what I need, but I am not sure what phrase to Google, or what is the algorithm category.

Here is my problem: I have a polyhedron made up by several contacting blocks (hyperslabs), i. e. the edges are axis aligned and the angles between edges are 90°. There may be holes inside the polyhedron.

I want to break up this concave polyhedron in as little convex rectangular axis-aligned whole blocks are possible (if the original polyhedron is convex and has no holes, then it is already such a block, and therefore, the solution). To illustrate, some 2-D images I made (but I need the solution for 3-D, and preferably, N-D):

I have this geometry:

[image: Original]

One possible breakup into blocks is this:

[image: Possible]

But the one I want is this (with as few blocks as possible):

[image: Correct]

I have the impression that an exact algorithm may be too expensive (is this problem NP-hard?), so an approximate algorithm is suitable.

One detail that maybe make the problem easier, so that there could be a more appropriated/specialized algorithm for it is that all edges have sizes multiple of some fixed value (you may think all edges sizes are integer numbers, or that the geometry is made up by uniform tiny squares, or voxels).

Background: this is the structured grid discretization of a PDE domain.

What algorithm can solve this problem? What class of algorithms should I 
search for?

Comment: Is it known if the edges of the given shape are aligned with X and Y axes?

Comment: Yes, yes. The way I wrote up there was: "...the edges are axis aligned..." Did you miss it? Is it not clear?

Comment: There is a very similar question here without an answer, however it does mention various methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749067/how-to-efficiently-cluster-voxel-space-into-the-fewest-number-of-similar-contig?rq=1

Comment: What is the format of your input? List of filled cells? CSG tree? BSP tree? Something else?

Comment: It is not exactly that, but you may say it is a list of voxel centers. All voxels are of the same size.

Comment: Are the (hyper)planes that are used to break up the blocks infinite? For example if you had a [ - shaped block, could you chop off the top horizontal bar with a vertical line without chopping off the bottom one?

Comment: @lvella: Thanks; sorry, I missed that initially.

Comment: @samgak No, that just happened to be the case in my example.

Comment: looks like variation of **ear clipping** problem may help. I would also give a try to search about **bin-packing** and **partitioning 2D space**

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Before you upvote that answer, I want to point out that my answer is slightly off-topic. The original poster have a question about the decomposition of a polyhedron with faces that are axis-aligned. Given such kind of polyhedron, the question is to decompose it into convex parts. And the question is in 3D, possibly nD. My answer is about the decomposition of a general polyhedron. So when I give an answer with a given implementation, that answer applies to the special case of polyhedron axis-aligned, but it might be that there exists a better implementation for axis-aligned polyhedron. And when my answer says that a problem for generic polyhedron is NP-complete, it might be that there exists a polynomial solution for the special case of axis-aligned polyhedron. I do not know.

Now here is my (slightly off-topic) answer, below the horizontal rule...

---

The [CGAL C++ library](http://www.cgal.org/) has an algorithm that, given a 2D polygon, can compute the optimal convex decomposition of that polygon. The method is mentioned in [the part **2D Polygon Partitioning** of the manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/index.html). The method is named [`CGAL::optimal_convex_partition_2`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/group__PkgPolygonPartitioning2.html#ga3ca9fb1f363f9f792bfbbeca65ad5cc5). I quote the manual:

> This function provides an implementation of [Greene's dynamic programming algorithm for optimal partitioning](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/citelist.html#CITEREF_g-dpcp-83) [2]. This algorithm requires O(n<sup>4</sup>) time and O(n<sup>3</sup>) space in the worst case.

In the [bibliography of that CGAL chapter](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/citelist.html), the article [2] is:

> [2] Daniel H. Greene. The decomposition of polygons into convex parts. In Franco P. Preparata, editor, *Computational Geometry*, volume 1 of *Adv. Comput. Res.*, pages 235–259. JAI Press, Greenwich, Conn., 1983.

It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Note that the same chapter of the CGAL manual also mention an approximation, hence not optimal, that run in O(n): [`CGAL::approx_convex_partition_2`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Partition_2/group__PkgPolygonPartitioning2.html#gab9cf8c2b097fd562da09dd23d0c74edf).

**Edit, about the 3D case:**

In 3D, CGAL has [another chapter about **Convex Decomposition of Polyhedra**](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/index.html). The second paragraph of the chapter says "this problem is known to be NP-hard [[1]](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/citelist.html#CITEREF_c-cpplb-84)". The reference [1] is:

> [1] Bernard Chazelle. Convex partitions of polyhedra: a lower bound and worst-case optimal algorithm. *SIAM J. Comput.*, 13:488–507, 1984.

CGAL has a method [`CGAL::convex_decomposition_3`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/group__PkgConvexDecomposition3.html#ga052b6dc92de74f6c273532c0c42fbff6) that computes a non-optimal decomposition.

Comment: @CortAmmon No. In CGAL there is [another chapter about **Convex Decomposition of Polyhedra**](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/index.html) in 3D. The second paragraph says "this problem is known to be NP-hard".

Comment: @CortAmmon I have modified my answer to speak about the 3D case. The dD is NP-hard as well, and CGAL does not provide any non-optimal implementation.

Comment: I like this answer, but my restrictions on the decomposition are more than just "convex" decomposition, I need axis aligned hyperslabs. So, in the practical sense, this answer may helps, but I will need to study and try to modify the algorithms to comply with the restriction (thanks for the references). On the theoretical sense, I'm afraid it is not immediately obvious that the complexities holds, because my problem is a little more restricted, thus may be easier to compute.

Comment: Well, I agree that my answer is slightly off-topic. I did not read the question carefull enough.

Answer (score 2):

I have the feeling your problem is NP-hard. I suggest a first step might be to break the figure into sub-rectangles along all hyperplanes. So in your example there would be three hyperplanes (lines) and four resulting rectangles. Then the problem becomes one of recombining rectangles into larger rectangles to minimize the final number of rectangles. Maybe 0-1 integer programming?

Comment: I think breaking it down like this, and then converting it into a problem for Z3 would be a good place to start. If you're lucky, Z3 does a speedy job and you don't have to think about how to search the space of choices. You also have some more confidence you haven't missed a case, and found a suboptimal solution.

Comment: The problem is known to be O(n^4) in 2D, and NP-hard in 3D. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30643519/1728537

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I am not convinced the same complexities for "plain" convex decomposition holds for my problem, because mine is more restricted.

Answer (score 1):

I think dynamic programming might be your friend.

The first step I see is to divide the polyhedron into a trivial collection of blocks such that every possible face is available (i.e. slice and dice it into the smallest pieces possible).  This should be trivial because everything is an axis aligned box, so k-tree like solutions should be sufficient.

This seems reasonable because I can look at its cost.  The cost of doing this is that I "forget" the original configuration of hyperslabs, choosing to replace it with a new set of hyperslabs.  The only way this could lead me astray is if the original configuration had something to offer for the solution.  Given that you want an "optimal" solution for all configurations, we have to assume that the original structure isn't very helpful.  I don't know if it can be proven that this original information is useless, but I'm going to make that assumption in this answer.

The problem has now been reduced to a graph problem similar to a constrained spanning forest problem.  I think the most natural way to view the problem is to think of it as a graph coloring problem (as long as you can avoid confusing it with the more famous graph coloring problem of trying to color a map without two states of the same color sharing a border).  I have a graph of nodes (small blocks), each of which I wish to assign a color (which will eventually be the "hyperslab" which covers that block).  I have the constraint that I must assign colors in hyperslab shapes.

Now a key observation is that not all possibilities must be considered. Take the final colored graph we want to see.  We can partition this graph in any way we please by breaking any hyperslab which crosses the partition into two pieces.  However, not every partition is meaningful.  The only partitions that make sense are axis aligned cuts, which always break a hyperslab into two hyperslabs (as opposed to any more complicated shape which could occur if the cut was not axis aligned).

Now this cut is the reverse of the problem we're really trying to solve.  That cutting is actually the thing we did in the first step.  While we want to find the optimal merging algorithm, undoing those cuts.  However, this shows a key feature we will use in dynamic programming: the only features that matter for merging are on the exposed surface of a cut.  Once we find the optimal way of forming the central region, it generally doesn't play a part in the algorithm.

So let's start by building a collection of hyperslab-spaces, which can define not just a plain hyperslab, but any configuration of hyperslabs such as those with holes.  Each hyperslab-space records:

- The number of leaf hyperslabs contained within it (this is the number we are eventually going to try to minimize)
- The internal configuration of hyperslabs.
- A map of the surface of the hyperslab-space, which can be used for merging.

We then define a "merge" rule to turn two or more adjacent hyperslab-spaces into one:

- Hyperslab-spaces may only be combined into new hyperslab-spaces (so you need to combine enough pieces to create a new hyperslab, not some more exotic shape)
- Merges are done simply by comparing the surfaces.  If there are features with matching dimensionalities, they are merged (because it is trivial to show that, if the features match, it is always better to merge hyperslabs than not to)

Now this is enough to solve the problem with brute force.  The solution will be NP-complete for certain.  However, we can add an additional rule which will drop this cost dramatically: "One hyperslab-space is deemed 'better' than another if they cover the same space, and have exactly the same features on their surface.  In this case, the one with fewer hyperslabs inside it is the better choice."

Now the idea here is that, early on in the algorithm, you will have to keep track of all sorts of combinations, just in case they are the most useful.  However, as the merging algorithm makes things bigger and bigger, it will become less likely that internal details will be exposed on the surface of the hyperslab-space.  Consider

```
+===+===+===+---+---+---+---+
|   :   : A | X :   :   :   :
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   :   : B | Y :   :   :   :
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   :   :   |   :   :   :   :
+===+===+===+   +---+---+---+
```

Take a look at the left side box, which I have taken the liberty of marking in stronger lines.  When it comes to merging boxes with the rest of the world, the AB:XY surface is all that matters.  As such, there are only a handful of merge patterns which can occur at this surface

- No merges possible
- A:X allows merging, but B:Y does not
- B:Y allows merging, but A:X does not
- Both A:X and B:Y allow merging (two independent merges)
- We can merge a larger square, AB:XY

There are many ways to cover the 3x3 square (at least a few dozen).  However, we only need to remember the best way to achieve each of those merge processes.  Thus once we reach this point in the dynamic programming, we can forget about all of the other combinations that can occur, and only focus on the best way to achieve each set of surface features.

In fact, this sets up the problem for an easy greedy algorithm which explores whichever merges provide the best promise for decreasing the number of hyperslabs, always remembering the best way to achieve a given set of surface features.  When the algorithm is done merging, whatever that final hyperslab-space contains is the optimal layout.

I don't know if it is provable, but my gut instinct thinks that this will be an O(n^d) algorithm where d is the number of dimensions.  I think the worst case solution for this would be a collection of hyperslabs which, when put together, forms one big hyperslab.  In this case, I believe the algorithm will eventually work its way into the reverse of a k-tree algorithm.  Again, no proof is given... it's just my gut instinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a constrained delaunay triangulation. It gives very few triangles.

Comment: Except that triangles are not convex rectangular axis-aligned whole blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to determine the equations for each line? 
If so, maybe you can get the intersection (points) between those lines. Then if you take one axis, and start to look for a value which has more than two points (sharing this value) then you should "draw" a line. (At the beginning of the sweep there will be zero points, then two (your first pair) and when you find more than two points, you will be able to determine which points are of the first polygon and which are of the second one.

Eg, if you have those lines:

verticals (red):

x = 0, x = 2, x = 5

horizontals (yellow):

y = 0, y = 2, y = 3, y = 5

[image: Image with lines and points]

and you start to sweep through of X axis, you will get p1 and p2, (and we know to which line-equation they belong ) then you will get p3,p4,p5 and p6 !! So here you can check which of those points share the same line of p1 and p2. In this case p4 and p5. So your first new polygon is p1,p2,p4,p5.
Now we save the 'new' pair of points (p3, p6) and continue with the sweep until the next points. Here we have p7,p8,p9 and p10, looking for the points which share the line of the previous points (p3 and p6) and we get p7 and p10. Those are the points of your second polygon.

When we repeat the exercise for the Y axis, we will get two points (p3,p7) and then just three (p1,p2,p8) ! On this case we should use the farest point (p8) in the same line of the new discovered point.

As we are using lines equations and points 2 or more dimensions, the procedure should be very similar

ps, sorry for my english :S

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It doesn't seems this procedure can guarantee I'll get the minimum number of blocks possible...

Comment: mmm, what if you choose the axis with less lines, in this case the vertical lines.